# I am having problems with rendering in Sony Vegas Pro 12

Tags: youtube, upload, rendering, high-definition, sony-vegas

I like to play games on Xbox 360 so I brought a HD PVR to record the gameplay too. The HD PVR if you are not familiar with is a device that records everything that is happening on the Xbox 360 it records Audio and Video. I want to upload the clips that I record with my HD PVR on to Youtube I can upload the Raw file which just has the Video and Audio but I also wanted to upload my commentating over the gameplay and that's why I got myself Sony Vegas Pro 12.

The problem I get is when I begin to render the "Approximate time left" will just keep on counting for example I left it on over night and it went to 24Hr and the percentage bar for how much has rendered had stayed on 0% when I checked in the morning the next day. I have tried so many different things to try and fix it I have looked everywhere but can't find a solution or why the problem is happening. Please when you ask me to do things to try and tell me in the most simplistic way.

The file recorded with my HD PVR is already HD 720p and its a 10 minute video to be exact its a 10:47 second video and the file size is 659 MB.

My Computer Specifications are,

- Intel i5-2430M @ 2.40GHz, 2401 MHz, 2 Core(s)
- 6GB Ram
- 750GB Hard Drive
- If you do need more Specifications please ask. I'm not to experienced with Sony Vegas.

I have tried a lot of different methods of rendering it which I have gotten off Youtube from other Youtubers that are doing the exact same thing as me.

[I have done these setting by a Youtuber called Wepeeler.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UYzWrAUGg4Q)

[I believe the current setting I seem to be using at the moment is from this Youtuber which is a lower rendering stranded.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=492QzTQYpOo)

It didn't allow me to post up pictures so instead I am giving all the information of properties.

Sony Vegas Pro "Render As" Video Properties.

```
Mode - CBR
Format - Window Media Video 9
Image Size - High Definition (1280x720)
Pixel aspect Ratio - 1.000 (Square)
Frame Rate (fps) - 29.970 (NTSC) Seconds per keyframe - 5
Video Smoothness - 69 (Sharper)
```

Sony Vegas Pro "Render As" Audio Properties.

```
Mode - CBR 
Format - Windows Media Audio 9.2
Attributes - 96kbps, 44kHz, stereo (A/V) CBR
```

The file I want to render Video Properties.

```
Video
Length 00:10:47
Frame width  - 1280
Frame Height - 720
Date Rate    - 8296kbps
Total Bitrate- 8552kbps
Frame rae    - 59 frames/second

Audio 
Bit Rate     - 256 kbps
Channels     - 2 (stereo)
Audio sample rate - 48kHz
```

Thank You for reading if you do need any more information please ask! I really appreciate your help!